Is the rule for unsigned integer overflow, the carry in matches the carry out?
I'm reading a textbook on systems programming and it states that an overflow occurs for unsigned integers if and only if the carry-in bit is mismatched with the carry-out, in the left-most bit.
So if using four bits and we add 1111 with 0001, it seems like this is saying that, because the right-most bit sum has a carry, and it eventually carries all the way left, the carry-in of the left-most bit is 1.  But its carry-out is also 1, so they match, so this is not an overflow.
But that seems exactly wrong to me.  In unsigned integers this is 15+1 which results in 0, which should be an overflow, yes?  Hence I wanted confirmation if I'm thinking about this correctly.
The rule that there is overflow with the carry-in and carry-out bits mismatch, is the rule for 2's complement numbers, and not for unsigned integers, right?
For unsigned integers, I believe the rule should be: There is overflow if and only if the left-most bit's carry-out is 1.

You are correct.

@EricPostpischil That's what I thought, except that the textbook explicitly states that it is describing overflow of unsigned integers.  So I think it's an error in the textbook.  The book is Dive into Systems, chapter 4, section 5, "The shortcut for unsigned arithmetic is: the carry out must match the carry in, otherwise the operation causes overflow. Intuitively, this shortcut works because:"  It seems like not an isolated error either, as in the paragraph above it also speaks about unsigned integer arithmetic, and then before that too.

The passage the question refers to appears to be “Unsigned Overflow” in section 4.5.2 of Dive Into Systems by Suzanne J. Matthews, Tia Newhall, and Kevin C. Webb, available here. In this, the authors describe addition of two operands in the usual way with carry-in of 0 to the low bit. For addition, this carry-in does not change the arithmetic. Overflow occurs if  and only if the carry-out of the high bit is 1, which is identical to if and and if the carry-out does not match the carry-in.
For subtraction, the authors use this algorithm:

Bitwise complement (one’s complement) the subtrahend.
Add the minuend and the complemented subtrahend with a carry-in of 1 to the low bit.

This is equivalent to adding the two’s complement of the subtrahend to the minuend. Since, in two’s complement, the two’s complement of a number is its negation, we can see this effects a subtraction.
If the carry-out is 0, the addition step (considered as an addition) did not overflow, and the result is greater than the minuend. This is an error for subtraction; a non-overflowing subtraction will produce a result less than or equal to the minuend. If the carry-out is 1, the addition did overflow and did produce a result less than or equal to the minuend, which is a non-overflow case for subtraction. Thus, we see the subtraction overflows if and only if the carry-out does not match the carry-in, 1.
The case where the subtrahend is zero is worth considering. If we took the two’s complement of the subtrahend, zero, that would be zero, and then adding the minuend and the zero would produce a carry-out of 0. However, the algorithm adds the minuend and the one’s complement of the subtrahend and a carry-in of 1. In this addition, the carry-out is 1, which is the result we desire, as it indicates there is no overflow for the subtraction.'
The authors’ specification of overflow detection in unsigned addition and subtraction is correct in the context of the algorithms they use.

I'm not seeing where they specify that the carry-in for the most significant bit is zero.  I see where they specify that it is zero for the units digit, the lease significant digit, and that makes sense.  But until they get to that part, the description that the carry-in must match the carry-out seems not to make sense, since as far as I can tell they never specify the carry-in to the most significant digit.

In any case, my question is mostly to make sure that I know what the rule is for unsigned integer arithmetic overflow -- and as far I can tell, my description was correct.  So that is really the answer to my question.
